# Matching security group names based on $variable.name

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

Ok so I'm trying to automate the creation of security groups under a specific OU. The keystone is group membership, so basically `If member of group A -> create group B.`

So I'm filling a variable with the name attribute of an "All Managers" group. Then I want to loop through those $names and check for the existence of another group using `{Name -like 'Reports to $name'}`

The looping part is throwing me off, here's what I've got:

```
import-module activedirectory

$ou = "ou=Stuff, ou=Resources, ou=Groups, ou=Org, dc=domain, dc=net"


$creds = "domain.net\user"
$server = "<domain controller>"



$managers = get-adGroupMember -server $server -Credential $creds -identity "All Managers" | select name
$name = $managers.name

    $ReportsTo = Get-adgroup -server $server -credential $creds -searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Reports to *'" | where {$_.name -replace 'Reports to ' -in $name} | select name
$Reports = $reportsto.name
$reports

    
     
ForEach ($manager in $managers){
    
    If ($ReportsTo -NotContains $name)
    #{$name}
    {New-ADGroup -name "Reports to "$name -groupscope Global -path $ou}

}
```

it's ugly I know, but like i said I'm not sure how to process the loop, they are still new to me.

Comment: You could do something like this: `$ReportsTo = Get-adgroup -server $server -credential $creds -filter "Name -like 'Reports to *'" | where {$_.Name -replace 'Reports to ' -in $name}` for all the managers who already have a group name

Comment: Blast! You certainly fixed one issue that I did not realize I had.  this totally gets me a listing of all the Reports to groupsReports to that match the Manager names.

Comment: Updated code above.

Comment: So I still need help with the looping part. I've updating the code above again with something that does not quite work for me.

Comment: hi, im still a little confused on what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate more on where you're having the issue

Comment: I think you want `foreach ($manager in $name) { if ($manager -notin ($reports -replace 'Reports to ')) { new-adgroup -name "Reports to $manager" -groupscope global -path $ou }}`

Comment: This might just be the answer.. one thing tho running the script threw the error: "new-adgroup : the specific group already exists" and I changed my $ou value to an empty test OU.  when I refreshed the OU it was full of security groups.. so Im unsure what was generating the errors.

Comment: `Name` is not a unique attribute value for all of AD. It is only unique in an OU. So you could have `John Jones` in OU1 and `John Jones` in OU2. Since your manager search is not looking into a specific OU, it may have multiple user objects with the same `Name` value. We could remove duplicates from `$managers` but that would also mean removing a real user from the list. Maybe your group names should use manager `SamAccountName` values or something else unique in AD.

Comment: interesting, but my $ou variable does limit things down to the exact OU that I'm worried about. I did also discover something new earlier..if I have two Adams in this OU only the first is caught and a reports to group created for him.  and I have less than zero idea on how to remedy that.

Comment: Oh wait I see what you mean.. checking the switches for Get-Adgroupmember I don't see a nice way to narrow it down.   Also, by setting the identity to "All Managers" (provided there are no other group objects with that name in other OU;s) shouldnt that be narrowed down enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following:

```
$ou = 'ou=Stuff,ou=Resources,ou=Groups,ou=Org,dc=domain,dc=net'
$creds = "domain.net\user"
$server = "<domain controller>"

# Get Manager names only
$managers = Get-ADGroupMember -Server $server -Credential $creds -Identity 'All Managers' |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Get Group names that are in the format Reports to Manager Name
$ReportsTo = Get-ADGroup -Server $server -Credential $creds -SearchBase $ou -Filter "Name -like 'Reports to *'" |
    where {$_.Name -replace 'Reports to ' -in $managers} |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Find manager names that don't have a Reports to group
Compare-Object $managers ($ReportsTo -replace 'Reports to ') -PassThru | Foreach-Object {
    # Pipe found manager names into New-ADGroup command's -Name parameter
    New-ADGroup -Name "Reports to $_" -GroupScope Global -Path $ou -Server $server -Credential $creds
}
```

[Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1) by default only lists differences.

Comment: getting an error when I run this one:  New-ADGroup :                                                  The name provided is not a properly formed account name
At line:24 char:5
+     New-ADGroup -Name "Reports to $_" -GroupScope Global -Path $ou
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Reports to @...dc=jamf, dc=net:String) [New-ADGroup], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1315,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADGroup
And no groups are created...

Comment: I want to vote this as my solution, but it's skipping a few users in the All Managers group and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: What is the name values of those users? Are the names in a different format than the others? Do groups already exist with those names?

Comment: Bingo.. got a second set of eyes at work and yes all the user groups that were missing, existed elsewhere. So by changing "Reports to" to "Report to" the script ran and created everything it needed to.  Thanks for all your help!  I will be posting more questions!